# Smart Capture Submission only working in Chrome

Tags: cloudpage, smart-capture

I have a basic form just capturing data and pushing into a simple DE. form/data capture works fine in chrome but not in any other browser we have tried.

Am i missing something i should have enabled to allow it to work in IE, edge, safari...?
Thanks,

Comment: @user69469-->your telling its not working in another browsers expect chrome ?

Comment: I have now managed to get it working in everything but IE by changing all fields to not required. But for some reason it just refreshes the page when you submit the form in IE.